# Facebook "like", how to set it to redirect to the wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, user-interface, facebook-graph-api, dom-events

I created a Facebook iframe for the initial landing page ("click like"). I have read in some previous posts that there was a Facebook bug previously that would redirect the landing page to the wall page. In fact, this is what initially my iframe did. Now, however, when a fan clicks "like" it is refreshing the page and staying on that original tab that was created. Seems that Facebook fixed the bug but now my landing page is refreshed when I really want it to go to the wall. I have found some people say that this piece of Javascript works to redirect the default tab to another tab...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top != self) top.window.location = 'http://URL-OF-DESTINATION-TAB';
</script>
```

but I want it back to the wall again, any ideas on how I can do this or what the url would be in the Javascript to take it to the wall?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite right. You can use the following URL to redirect to the wall tab:

```
http://www.facebook.com/<pagename>?sk=wall
```

Be sure to only redirect to the wall only after people liked your page. You can find a nice tutorial on how to do that on:

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/customizing-facebook-iframe-application-signed_request_reveal_tab/

Good luck!